# .htaccess how to show 503 for a specific URL on a website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to show 503 error on a specific URL of my website. This should only apply to that specific URL and other pages should load fine. So far I've tried the following with no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Our website is temporarily closed for scheduled maintenance."
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !http://example.com/myspeicifcpage$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know for which url it needs to show 503?

Comment: Hi, I don't want it to be redirect actually. Just want to show a default 503.

Comment: To clarify it further, this is the URL that I want to show the 503. 
Suppose I have a 3-page website

https://example.com/
https://example.com/a
https://example.com/b

I want to show a 503 error when a user visits http://example.com/a. But the other URLs should be accessible fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it, all urls for this domain you want to get 503? Or only with `a/` and `b/` and with domain name? Please confirm once.

Comment: Hi, just want to show it for the /a page. Other pages should load fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Our website is temporarily closed for schedule maintenance"
Redirect 503 /specificPage
```

This will print the error text on `/specificPage` if it is accessed.

You can also markup the error message using html tags

```
ErrorDocument 503 "<b>Our website is temporarily closed for schedule maintenance.</b>"
Redirect 503 /specificPage
```

Answer (score 3):

For your mentioned URLs you could try following, this will look for specific urls like `http://localhost:80/` or `http://localhost:80/a` or `http://localhost:80/b`.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /league.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(a|b)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

---

---

OR In case you want to get 503 for any page for domain name `example.com` then you could try following.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /league.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```